# как сделать уникальный префикс для сервера discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать уникальный префикс для каждого сервера на котором находится бот. Допустим чтобы на одном сервере пользователь мог поставить для бота тот префикс, который хочет и это бы не влияло на префиксы на других серверах. Необходимо чтобы работало с декоратором `@bot.command()`. Возможно ли обойтись без `on_message`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В аргумент `command_prefix` конструктора бота можно передавать функцию, которая будет возвращать необходимый префикс в зависимости от сообщения: [Bot.command_prefix](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix)

```py
GUILD_PREFIXES = {840938031829325150: "?"}

def guild_based_prefix(bot, message):
    return GUILD_PREFIXES.get(message.guild.id, "!")

bot = commands.Bot(prefix=guild_based_prefix)
```

Таким образом, на сервере с ID `840938031829325150` все команды будут выполняться с префиксом `?`, а на остальных серверах - с префиксом `!`